# В чем ошибка запроса SQL?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Выполняю sql запрос: https://pastebin.com/izaAV8kZ

Выдает: #1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около '' на строке 10

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце последней строки `(176, 'Российская Федерация', 'RU', 'RUS', '', 0, 1),` надо не запятую, а точку с запятой поставить

```
(176, 'Российская Федерация', 'RU', 'RUS', '', 0, 1);
```